# How to show if $X$ is Killing field then it is tangent to the geodesic spheres centred at a point $p$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannianiam manifold with Levi-Civita connection and $X $ be a smooth vector field on $M$. Let $\phi : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) × V \to M$ be the local flow of $X$ in $M$.

Problem is- if $X$ is a killing field on $M $, $p \in M$ and $U$ be a normal neighborhood of $p$. If $p$ is the unique point satisfying $X(p)= 0$ then in $U$, $X$ is tangent to the geodesic spheres centred at $p$.

My attempt: With some hints, I've got from here and there, I know that first, we need to have that $\phi(t,p) = p \forall t\in(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which I am able to show.

Next, I think to show the required, it suffices to show that for any $q \in exp_{p}(S(0,\epsilon) = S_({p}(\epsilon))$, a geodesic sphere contained  in $U$ which is of the form $q= exp_{p}(v)$ for some $v$ such that $|v|=\epsilon$, the radial vector joining $p$ to $q$ is orthogonal to $X(q)$.

But I don't know how to proceed to show this. 
Also, where do we use the uniqueness of point $p$ as the only zero of $X$?

It would be lovely if anyone could provide me some hint to solve this. 
Thank you!!

Comment: I don't think the uniqueness is needed here. The thing is that the flow of $X$ is isometric, and so at any time it carries a point $q$ to a point which has the same distance from $p$.

Comment: Hmm...but why would the author mention about $p$ being unique though? One of the answer/hint I got mentioned ' the reason we want $p$ to be an isolated zero point of $X$ is because we want to show a nontrivial $X(q)$ is tangent to the geodesic sphere centered at $p$, at each point $q \in S(p,\epsilon)$ ', could you explain it?

Comment: Edit in the above comment: the book says that $p$ is the unique point of $U$, normal neighborhood of $p$ such that $X(p)=0$